# Hints for evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,n]} (1-x/n)^n e^{x/3}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Hints for evaluating $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,n]} (1-x/n)^n e^{x/3}dx$$

Clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-x/n)^n \cdot e^{x/3}=e^{-2x/3}$, but can I switch the limit and the integral?

Comment: Yes, you can - dominated convergence theorem allows you to.

Comment: Right, of course. thanks